# Delete collection in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb

I have the following json file in mongodb:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59de156faf75d539b47e8db3"),
"user" : "user1",
"item" : {
    "32a1fsd32asfd65asdf65" : {
        ...
    },
    "32a1fsd32asfd555" : {

    }, ...
  }
}
```

I want to perform a query and delete one of the two items. As a matter of fact, my database contains several users. Therefore, in order to retrieve the specific one from the mongodb i am performing the following:

How can I retrieve also a specific item and delete all its fields (for example 32a1fsd32asfd65asdf65)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example document provided in your document it looks like you want to remove an attribute of the subdocument `item`.

You can use the [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) update operator:

```
db.getCollection('colName').update(
    // find a specific document
    {user: 'user1'}, 

    // unset the attribute named "sfd65asdf65"
    {$unset: {'item.sfd65asdf65': 1}}
)
```

Given the document provided in your question, the above command will cause that document to be updated to:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59de156faf75d539b47e8db3"),
    "user" : "user1",
    "item" : {
        "sd32asfd555" : {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to remove the `item` attribute entirely then you would run:

```
db.getCollection('colName').update(
    // find a specific document
    {user: 'user1'}, 

    // unset the attribute named "32a1fsd32asfd65asdf65"
    {$unset: {'item': 1}}
)
```

And if you want to empty the `item` attribute (i.e. remove all of its attributes but retain the `item` attribute) then you would run this command:

```
db.getCollection('colName').update(
    // find a specific document
    {user: 'user1'}, 

    // overwrite the "item" attribute with an empty sub document
    {$set: {'item': {}}}
)
```

You can find more examples [in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/#example).

Comment: Does item and id requires apostrophe? Also do i need the id variable? I tried and it didnt work. I am receiving: Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value

Comment: Could you update your question to include a sample document (rather than a screenshot showing part of the document)? It would be easier to provide a complete answer if I had a sample document to work on.

Comment: Yes already update the image with the json file. I want to delete for exampe the item with the name "32a1fsd32asfd65asdf65"

Comment: Still not sure if I need to have apostrophe or not and for example i tried to use that to your code: {item: {"32a1fsd32asfd65asdf65"}} and it didnt work.

Comment: This: `{item: {"32a1fsd32asfd65asdf65"}}` would be true if `item` contained a string attribute with the value `"32a1fsd32asfd65asdf65"`. But item is actually a sub document not a String. Also, having re-read your question after you pasted in th example document it's now clear that you are dealing with a sub document **not** an array so I have updated the answer accordingly. Apologies for the confusion earlier.

Comment: No, of course dont worry, the confusion was because I posted the image instead of the real json.

Answer (score 1):

Say we have some users:

```
> db.test.insert( { _id: 1, user: "bob", field1: 1, field2 :{ field3 : 2 } } )
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test.insert( { _id: 2, user: "fred", field1: 1, field2 :{ field3 : 2 } } )
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

We can then use `replaceOne` to find the user and also then just replace the whole document, thus removing all the fields from that document:

```
> db.test.replaceOne( { user: "bob"}, { user: "bob" } )
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }
```

Then our new documents will look like:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "user" : "bob" }
{ "_id" : 2, "user" : "fred", "field1" : 1, "field2" : { "field3" : 2 } }
```